# Can i use fetch to authorise with Strapi from Nuxt 3

Tags: strapi, nuxtjs3

I am trying to make login work for a user with strapi 4 and nuxt 3 but i get a bad request error. I would like to use fetch to do this, log out etc... is that possible?

Can anyone see my error please, works in postman

My code is as follows

```
<script setup>

    const userName= ref("")
    const  userPassword = ref("")

    const createLogin = async () => { 
        await $fetch("http://localhost:1337/api/auth/local", {
        method: "POST",
        body: {
        data: {
                identifier: userName.value,
                password: userPassword.value
                }
            }
        })
        console.log('Worked!');
    }

</script>

<template>
    <div>
        <div>User: <input type="text" v-model="userName" /></div>
        <div>Password: <input type="text" v-model="userPassword" /></div>
        <button @click="createLogin">Log In</button>
    </div>
</template>
```

Thanks for looking

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out

For anyone else with same issue dont need the data in the function

```
<script setup>

    const userName= ref("")
    const  userPassword = ref("")

    const createLogin = async () => { 
        await $fetch("http://localhost:1337/api/auth/local", {
        method: "POST",
        body: {

                identifier: userName.value,
                password: userPassword.value
              }

        })
        console.log('Worked!');
    }

</script>
```